# Calling one of my Main Activity Method From another Class Returns an Error

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

MAIN ACTIVITY

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SecondActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}


public void function(String data) {
    EditText editText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText);
    editText.setText(data);

}
```

}

here is my SECOND ACTIVITY

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity {
MainActivity mainActivity=new MainActivity();
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle save){
    super.onCreate(save);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout2);
    Button button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String data="SUCCESS!";
            mainActivity.function(data);
        }
    });

}
```

}

Here is the Error

```
10-07 20:56:47.678 11920-11920/wifiexplorer.braveheart.com.classtest E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: wifiexplorer.braveheart.com.classtest, PID: 11920
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:68)
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:145)
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV11.java:28)
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV14.java:41)
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV23.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV23.java:29)
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:186)
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:170)
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:502)
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.findViewById(AppCompatActivity.java:174)
   at wifiexplorer.braveheart.com.classtest.MainActivity.function(MainActivity.java:20)
   at wifiexplorer.braveheart.com.classtest.SecondActivity$1.onClick(SecondActivity.java:22)
   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5277)
   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21711)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5896)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
```

I am new to android Programming, here i just use an intent to call my second Activity.

Comment: that not the way activity work in android, if you want to pass data from one activity to another activity, you can use `Bundle`

Comment: then we cannot send/receive datas from one activity to another activity by passing arguments?? am i right?

Comment: yes it can, see @user123456 answer

Comment: how we can call a method of Activity from another activity?? how it is possible?

Comment: You don't... Activities are not available at the same time. When you `new` an Activity, it is unmanaged. The `Window` and `Context` of it is then null, so therefore, your error. The link in the answer below has been fixed

Comment: Okay! so, in android we can't call a specific method in an Activity from another activity. am i right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this documentation ["Getting a Result from an Activity"](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html)

You want to update your ui element. Good practice in your case is use **startActivityForResult**. Example code in your case:

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String STRING_RESULT_DATA_KEY = "result_data";

    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_SECOND_ACTIVITY = 101;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_SECOND_ACTIVITY);
    }

    public void function(String data) {
        EditText editText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText);
        editText.setText(data);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // Check which request we're responding to
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_SECOND_ACTIVITY) {
            // Make sure the request was successful
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                String dataString = data.getStringExtra(STRING_RESULT_DATA_KEY);
                function(dataString);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

SecondActivity:

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.second_activity);
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String data = "SUCCESS!";
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.putExtra(MainActivity.STRING_RESULT_DATA_KEY, data);
                setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: how to call a specific method in Activity from another activity? in my example i need to call function in MainActivity from my SecondActivity. how i can do that?

Comment: Thank you user123456! but i have a doubt,
in 

"protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)"

 the parameter order?? 

in second activity 
the setResult  sets 
RESULT_OK to requestcode & MainActivity.STRING_RESULT_DATA_KEY -> resultCode &
data -> Intent data

But in "if condition" its not like that :P 
i didint uderstand the parameter order..

Comment: @BraveHeart MainActivity.STRING_RESULT_DATA_KEY is RequestCode to launch any activity that you want. You can start any activities from MainActivity. And you can handle with any activity result in your method onActivityResult using requestCode. 
RESULT_OK is ResultCode. Another activity can set RESULT_CANCELED for example if another activity doesn't want to send some data back.

Comment: **Thank you Verry Much!**

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is you are changing a visual element of an activity that is newly created, not necessarily drawn or inflated. Instead of calling the function on a page that doesn't exist yet, why not navigate to the main activity page on your on click and set a variable to the text you want to show?